# Execute commands with su from inside a python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, subprocess

I want to make a python program which changes user, supplies the password for su and executes a command. Without using SUDO. Preferably with subprocess

For example:

```
su testuser -c id > /tmp/test
```

I have wrote these scripts but they dont work.

```
import subprocess
su_password = ("Password\n")

proc = subprocess.Popen('su testuser -c id > /tmp/test', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(su_password)
proc.stdin.flush()
```

and this one with pexpect

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('su testuser')
child.expect('Password: ')
child.sendline('Password123456')
child.sendline('id > /tmp/TEST')
```

Comment: su gets the password from the terminal, not from standard input. Why don't you want to use sudo? It has a no password option, that can be combined with rules stating that only specific commands can be run - and by specific users

Comment: Yes i know that su gets the password from terminal, thats what i am trying to do. somehow make it think as it got it from the terminal. Not using sudo is a requirement

Comment: You could try wrapping it using the 'script' command (with -c option). Typing this on a phone so I can't really test it just now, but it may do what you need and allow the terminal input to be supplied on standard input.

Comment: @alani could you elaborate, i don't understand how to wrap it using 'script' command

Comment: Well, my earlier suggestion didn't seem to work, but I tried the `expect` solution at https://serverfault.com/a/894475/592132 and it works nicely. (Check your exact password prompt; the example there uses `"Password :"` but there is no space on my system.)

Comment: @alani yes i saw that answer. But can it be made python subprocess?